# JQuery textbox is not highlighting when 2 validators used for it asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want on validation color of required fields change. For this I have following code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        HighlightControlToValidate();
        $('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>').click(function() {
            if (typeof (Page_Validators) != "undefined") {
                for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                    if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                        $('#' + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).css("background", "#FFFF99");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#' + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).css("background", "white");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function HighlightControlToValidate() {
        if (typeof (Page_Validators) != "undefined") {
            for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {               
                $('#' + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).blur(function() {
                var validatorctrl = getValidatorUsingControl($(this).attr("ID"));                                
                    if (validatorctrl!= null && !validatorctrl.isvalid) {
                        $(this).css("background", "#FFFF99");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).css("background", "white");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }    
    function getValidatorUsingControl(controltovalidate) {       
        var length = Page_Validators.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (Page_Validators[j].controltovalidate == controltovalidate) {
                return Page_Validators[j];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }    
</script>
```

this code is working fine but for a textbox which has 2 validators one is required field and one is regular expression color is not changing. Following is code:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Summary Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="summary" Display="Dynamic" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only 255 characters allowed" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^.{1,255}$" ControlToValidate="summary" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Please someone help me what to do?

Comment: Could you show the generated html?

Comment: The one Validator overrides the other. If you want 2 conditions and a colred textbox then you can create a CustomValidator.